# Can't understand some array syntax

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

I found a MATLAB code like this one:

```
x = [1, ([1:(m-1)].^a)];
```

where `a` and `m` are scalar.

Could somebody explain that? I'm not so familiar with the MATLAB programming language.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/getstart.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `1:(m-1)` creates and array from `1` to `m-1` in steps of `1`.
- `.^a` raises each element in the previous array to the power `a` (`^` is a regular power and tries to compute the matrix power, the `.` makes operations element-wise, i.e. raise each element to power `a` instead of the whole matrix)
- `[1, y]` is simply the array `y` with a `1` prepended as first element.

Putting this all together we find that `x` is an array which starts with `1`, followed by an integer array `1:(m-1)` with each element raised to the power `a`.

```
m=5;a=3;
x = [1, ([1:(m-1)].^a)]
x =
     1     1     8    27    64
```

Broken down in steps:

```
tmp = 1:(m-1)
tmp =
     1     2     3     4
tmp2 = tmp.^a
ans =
     1     8    27    64
x = [1 tmp2]
x =
     1     1     8    27    64
```